# Set maximum value in raster .tif file in R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

is there a way to set a maximum value of the raster .tif file?

Currently,
values     : 0.9459136, 130889.8  (min, max)

but I want to set the max to be 100000

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `clamp` or `reclassify`. For example, with

```
library(raster)
logo <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
```

To set the maximum value to 100, you can do

```
x <- clamp(logo, -Inf, 100)
```

or

```
y <- reclassify(logo, cbind(100, Inf, 100))
```

Bappa Das' solution also works

```
logo[logo > 100] <- 100
```

But is intended for interactive use on smaller datasets, and does not have useful arguments like `filename`.

The new `terra` package (intended to replace `raster`) has the same functions (except that `reclassify` is called `classify`); and it also has `ifel` (if-else), as illustrated below

```
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))  
z <- ifel(s > 100, 100, s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
library(raster)

raster <- stack("raster_name")

raster[raster > 100000] <- NA
```